# How do you find Randal the Perfected?

Tags: destiny

Does anybody know how to find the elusive Randal in the wrath of the machine raid?

I've seen a couple videos showing "Randal, the Perfected", but the mystery remains unexplained.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Destiny Wiki](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Randal_the_Vandal):

> Rahndel, the Perfected appears as an Easter Egg in the Server Farm during the Wrath of the Machine raid. Like Randal, he also has an abnormally high amount of hit points.

It appears the Randal you are after spawns in the server farm during the raid.

The actual "Randal" (and when I say actual, I mean the original) spawns in the Forgotten Shore near a cave that connects to The Grottos.  If I remember right, he doesn't have a special name either.

Comment: He did not have a special name, but the Rahndel in the raid is a nod to the Vandal in the forgotten shores.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure if the Destiny wiki has a typo or if others are reporting incorrectly. I'm referring to the Randal in the raid. He certainly doesn't just "appear" after the server farm.

Comment: It doesn't say after the server farm but rather in it. Idk what the server farm is like, but maybe look for a secret spot to find him.